# Pickle Hangs with PyPy

Tags: python-2.7, pickle, pypy

My application hangs serializing a lists of dictionaries (CSV data) with pickle. Using the regular Python interpreter there are no issues. I am on Python 2.7, PyPy 2.6.0 for Win32.

Here is the output when I `Ctrl+C` the application:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<builtin>/app_main.py", line 75, in run_toplevel
  File ".\Da-Lite\dalite_build_script.py", line 167, in <module>
    pickle.dump(data_sheets, fo)
  File "H:\Developer\Python\pypy-2.6.0-win32\lib-python\2.7\pickle.py", line 1413, in dump
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "H:\Developer\Python\pypy-2.6.0-win32\lib-python\2.7\pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "H:\Developer\Python\pypy-2.6.0-win32\lib-python\2.7\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "H:\Developer\Python\pypy-2.6.0-win32\lib-python\2.7\pickle.py", line 653, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "H:\Developer\Python\pypy-2.6.0-win32\lib-python\2.7\pickle.py", line 667, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "H:\Developer\Python\pypy-2.6.0-win32\lib-python\2.7\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "H:\Developer\Python\pypy-2.6.0-win32\lib-python\2.7\pickle.py", line 653, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "H:\Developer\Python\pypy-2.6.0-win32\lib-python\2.7\pickle.py", line 667, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "H:\Developer\Python\pypy-2.6.0-win32\lib-python\2.7\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "H:\Developer\Python\pypy-2.6.0-win32\lib-python\2.7\pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "H:\Developer\Python\pypy-2.6.0-win32\lib-python\2.7\pickle.py", line 615, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "H:\Developer\Python\pypy-2.6.0-win32\lib-python\2.7\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "H:\Developer\Python\pypy-2.6.0-win32\lib-python\2.7\pickle.py", line 653, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "H:\Developer\Python\pypy-2.6.0-win32\lib-python\2.7\pickle.py", line 665, in _batch_setitems
    for k, v in items:
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Using Pickle is not essential to the program, but if there is a relatively simple solution to overcome this problem it makes my life easier.

Comment: how big is the data in the CSV file's, or the dictionaries ??

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple here - pickle on pypy is slower, because it's implemeneted in pure python as opposed to C in CPython

Comment: I get this... Should it be *a lot* slower? What took less than a second taking > 10 minutes? Why implement Pickle at all in PyPy?

Comment: it definitely should not be 1s -> 10min (more like say 2-5x slower). Can you share the example?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of dictionaries, a very straightforward thing to do would be to break up the list into several parts, and `dump` each portion of the list to a different file.  Something like this:

```
>>> d1 = dict(zip(range(10),range(10)))
>>> d2 = dict(zip(range(10,20),range(10,20)))
>>> d3 = dict(zip(range(20,30),range(20,30)))
>>> d4 = dict(zip(range(30,40),range(30,40)))
>>> x = [d1,d2,d3,d4]
>>> fnames = ['a.pik', 'b.pik', 'c.pik', 'd.pik']
>>> 
>>> import pathos
>>> p = pathos.pools.ProcessPool()
>>> 
>>> def dump(data, fname):
...   import dill
...   with open(fname, 'w') as f:
...     dill.dump(data, f)
...   return
... 
>>> r = p.uimap(dump, x, fnames)
>>> # no need to do this, but just FYI, it returns nothing
>>> list(r)
[None, None, None, None]
>>>
```

One thing to note, I'm using a fork of `multiprocessing` called `multiprocess` that is used by `pathos`… which provides a `multiprocessing` `map` that can take multiple arguments, reduces some of the overhead for starting a `map`, and has better serialization capabilities than `pickle`.

I'm using `uimap` because I don't care about maintaining the order of the return values (they are `None`). If your dictionaries are big, you may want to use processes… but depending on the size, you might try to use a thread pool, or even `imap` from `itertools`.  `pathos` provides them in a nice uniform API so you can switch easily and optimize for execution speed.

```
>>> pathos.pools.ProcessPool 
<class 'pathos.multiprocessing.ProcessPool'>
>>> pathos.pools.ThreadPool 
<class 'pathos.threading.ThreadPool'>
>>> pathos.pools.SerialPool 
<class 'pathos.serial.SerialPool'>
```

**NOTE:** I'm the author of `pathos`. I know it works in standard python.  I can't confirm that it works in `PyPy` at the moment however. I have had people try it, and have made patches to support `PyPy`, but I don't test in `PyPy`… so you'd have to try it and find out.  If `pathos` doesn't work on `PyPy`… then you'd have to modify the `dump` function to either take only one argument -- or to make sure you are using `itertools.imap`.  Regardless, the idea of breaking up the list into several chunks, and then serializing the chunks on different processes/threads/whatever is my main point.